# IPython deprecation warning when importing display

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, display

When I run:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

I got

> /var/folders/6g/6gqq4lhx4jbcl4_tbrsxj3xr0000gq/T/ipykernel_5625/333572366.py:1:
> DeprecationWarning: Importing display from IPython.core.display is
> deprecated since IPython 7.14, please import from IPython display
> from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I guess somebody did because that warning is rather unambiguous - *x is deprecated, use y* - and you didn't provide any further information, so it's not quite clear what the question is.

Comment: Not necessarily – the way I understand it, if somebody felt "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" (cf. the tooltip of the downvote button), downvoting is the proper way to provide feedback. Maybe next time, try to provide more details about what you tried to solve the problem. I wouldn't think too much of a single downvote.

Comment: @fsimonjetz The message is slightly ambiguous. If it said "please import from IPython.display" (notice the period), then it would be completely clear.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I guess a period there would be appropriate indeed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

replace

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
```

with

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
```

source [here](https://github.com/pytorch/captum/issues/936)